# Using STL algorithms with Qt containers

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, c++11, stl

I have a problem, using STL algorithm with QList: while executing it crashes. Debuger takes one more step into lambda, so before to crash entry is . (So, if list is empty is crashes at 1 iteration, if list has 1 element - at 2 iteration etc.).

```
void FindDialog::findEntries()
{
    QList<StudentEntry> searchResult;

    condition = [this] (const StudentEntry &entry) -> bool {
                // crashes here 
                return entry.name.getSurname() == surnameEdt1->text() &&
                       entry.group.getValue() == groupEdt->text();
                };

    std::copy_if(model->getStudentEntryList().begin(),
                 model->getStudentEntryList().end(),
                 searchResult.begin(),
                 condition);
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You probably want to use [`std::back_inserter(searchResult)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) as your output iterator

Comment: getStudentEntryList() doesn't return a copy, does it?

Comment: Your problem is not really Qt-related. It'll crash just the same with `std::list`. Have you looked at correct examples demonstrating the use of `copy_if`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) increments the output iterator when copying elements. You passed it `searchResult.begin()` which is equally an `end()` iterator since `searchResult` is an empty container. And increment(ing) an iterator passed the `end()` iterator invokes Undefined Behavior.

since `QList<T>` supports a `push_back(T)` member function, you should use [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to create a `std::back_insert_iterator` that will be doing push back's to `searchResult`

```
std::copy_if(model->getStudentEntryList().begin(),
             model->getStudentEntryList().end(),
             std::back_inserter(searchResult),
             condition);
```